# Uninstall Wordpress, website wont point to index.html

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, digital-ocean

I installed wordpress, then didn't really like it and decided to just build my site in HTML using bootstrap.

I created an `index.html` and dropped it into `/var/www/html`

but when I go to www.mysite.com it does not auto go to my index.html like it used to. `www.mysite.com/index.html` does work though

How can I uninstall wordpress or re-direct my site to my new index?

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file in the same folder?

Comment: I ran an ls and didnt see anything. Do I need more then a typical ls to see hidden files?

Comment: nope dont have that file. I even did a nano .htaccess to double check and it came up empty

Comment: You almost definitely do. WordPress adds it's own rules to `.htaccess` when you install. These rules would cause the exact problem you're having. If you add `index.php` and echo 'hello world' I bet that's what you'll get

Comment: If I have it, then its not in the /var/www/html